# Pass multiple values to popup on button click

Tags: jquery, laravel

How can I pass multiple values to a popup form through a button?

```html
<button class="btn btn-success edit-company" data-id="{{ $cp->companyId }}" data-name="{{ $cp->companyName }}" data-nature="{{ $cp->businessNature }}" data-address="{{ $cp->companyAddress }}" data-zip="{{ $cp->companyZipcode }}" data-area="{{ $cp->companyAddressArea }}" data-email="{{ $cp->companyEmail }}" data-phone="{{ $cp->companyPhoneNumber }}" data-website="{{ $cp->companyWebsite }}">
  <i class="fa fa-edit m-right-xs"></i>
  Edit Profile
</button>
```

Comment: Which popup are you using for it?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.edit-company').on('click',function(){
    var Name = $(this).data('name');
    // Here 'Name' will be having the value you passed to the popup
});
```

Comment: similarly you could use other items as well